# Access .NET DLLs from Java Based application, is a service wrapper acceptable?

Tags: java, .net, cross-platform

I have a large library of .NET DLLs that I'd like to leverage/re-use in a new context which is a Java-Based application.

My first thought is simply to wrap the library of DLLs with an MVC web application that would expose them through a simple REST based service call.

Each DLL contains a single class that implements the same standard interface, so a single service call with the DLL naming convention and the same parameters passed in should be able to facilitate loading up the DLL, no?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should do. Make sure use of a factory pattern with some key passed or some kind of logic to use correct DLL.

---

> May I know what is the result of the program from the DLL's. Just in
>   case if it doesn't return any data from the DLL only some backend
>   updates or writes to the disk or server, then simply create an exe
>   file and call from java application. This will be less expensive than
>   a web call.

Comment: it will potentially return data, yes.

Comment: Did you try this option? basically it loads dll into java like .net porting an external library to c#.  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/378826/How-to-Wrap-a-Csharp-Library-for-Use-in-Java

Comment: Any luck with it?